# Add a subtotal line in a Sales Quote

Tags: rdlc, dynamics-business-central

I need to allow Sales staff to add options in Quotes, and display a subtotal line under each option.

I'm thinking of using a couple of comment lines:
OPTHEAD (Sales will detail the option here, e.g., "Option 1: Full product line"
Sales Quote lines
SUBTOTAL

I'd like to replace the SUBTOTAL comment line when it is printed, with the total of lines between that and the Option Header. Along the lines of "Subtotal Option 1, $1000"

Could someone please provide me a pointer to achieve this? I'm having trouble finding guidance/documentation for this, but it must be a fairly common requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The method you mention is one possibility, however might be difficult to manage.

I suggest you add a new field to the `Sales Line` table e.g. `Sales Option` of type `Integer`. The field would also need to be added to the Sales Quote subform page.

The salesperson then needs to assign a value to the `Sales Option` field in order to group the lines into options.

The `Sales Option` should be added to the report dataset for each line which will enable you to group on it on the RDLC layout.

You can then add a sum per group.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a steer, much appreciated. That seems really logical. I'm thinking I could still use the Option Heading comment, and replace the line total with the calculated Option cost on the report.